# Accessing ng-templates in ViewChild and ViewChildren

Tags: angular

I have this template

```
 <ng-container #gridView>
          <ng-template #col1 let-row="row" let-column="column" colName="'abc'" colValue="'tableValue'" colWidth="'70px'" colEditable="'false'" colVisible="'true'">
              test1 cell {{row[column.value]}} 
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template #col_2 let-row="row" let-column="column" colName="'edf'" colValue="'tableValue2'" colWidth="'150px'" colEditable="'false'" colVisible="'true'">
              test1 cell {{row[column.value]}}
          </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
 <my-grid #grid></my-grid >
```

I want to be able to get a TemplateRef for each of the templates in my container (#col1, #col2, ect).

I have been able to use ViewChild to get a single TemplateRef

```
@ViewChild('col1') public col1: TemplateRef<any>
```

But what I want is to be able to get a collection of TemplateRefs.

I tried using viewChildren

```
@ViewChildren('gridView') gridTemplates: any;
```

This gives me a result of length one, when I would expect a result array with two members. The nativeEelement is a comment (which is not unexpected, but also not useful). How do I get my TemplateRefs from my QueryList?

Also, how can I get the attributes I have attached to my template?

I tried creating an attribute directive and using ContentChildren and ViewChildren with the directive as the selector, but without success.